# Could one see stars from Concorde in daytime?

Tags: supersonic, high-altitude, concorde

Concorde flew to an altitude of 60,000 ft (18.3 km) where stars should be visible at noon, aren't they? [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/73024/at-what-altitude-might-a-pilot-be-able-to-see-at-least-the-brightest-stars-durin) asks on how high stars become visible, and it is said Blackbird pilots could see them at 80,000 ft. Concorde flew at the [Armstrong line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong_limit) when highest, above more than 90% of the atmosphere's mass. Are there reports of passengers and pilots on Concorde seeing stars (other than the Sun) when at peak altitude? Also, did the Sun appear whiter due to the thinner atmosphere?

Comment: You can see Sirius from sea level. Climbing to 18 km doesn't change anything, still only Sirius. "*The daylight visibility of stars has been investigated for an observer altitude of 100 000 ft, using published visual threshold data and calculated sky luminance. Venus, Jupiter, and Sirius, plus Mars at its brighter phases, can be detected with the naked eye*", [source](https://www.osapublishing.org/josa/abstract.cfm?uri=josa-49-6-626). Sirius has a magnitude of -1.46 at sea level. At night an eye can see down to +6 only. Someone may build an answer starting with these elements.

Comment: @Someone -- there's nothing wrong with referring to the Concorde as "the Concorde", even if the accepted usage (for some weird reason, no other plane is treated this way, and this has been the subject of an ASE question https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/57085/34686) is simply "Concorde".  IMHO that was a totally superfluous edit (version #3).

Comment: @Someone-- actually, I forgot that *you* were the one who bountied that question not so long ago. Thanks, that was nice-- but I still do feel the recent edits are superfluous.

Comment: @quietflyer okay, I won't change it in old questions anymore. If I'm editing one anyway for another reason, should I change it then?

Comment: Your call-- I'd prefer you not on my own question, but I only asked one question about the Concorde, so prob won't be an issue. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Tell ya what: I'll attach a camera to a model rocket, put the biggest engine I can find on it, take it up in a plane and shoot that sucker out the window (or any available opening) and we'll see what the camera says. (I apologize for my informal language)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, in at least one exceptional circumstance.
The book [Racing the Moon’s Shadow with Concorde 001](https://www.springer.com/cn/book/9783319217284) describes a 1973 scientific flight that remained in the moon's umbra for more than an hour, in daytime.  As stars are quite visible from the ground during a solar eclipse's totality, they would have been even more visible from a 17 km altitude.

Comment: I don't think the question was asking about a solar eclipse! Even though it's technically "in **daytime**", the question is clearly about normal **daylight**.

Comment: I don't think so, either!  But I couldn't resist, that flight was just so cool.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune Sorry but during a total eclipse you can see them even from the sea level as you say yourself. :-)

Answer (score -2):

[This page](https://www.heritageconcorde.com/views-from-the-edge-of-space) has some images of the view from the Concorde. On one image two stars can be seen. So obviously one could see some.

Comment: Can't tell which photo you're referring to as having stars in it. Also, FWIW, even at midnight photos that size have a hard time depicting individual stars - they're just so tiny & pretty dim. Doesn't mean that stars are, or aren't, there for the eye to see, just that they're hard to capture in small photos with nearer (and much brighter) objects in view & in focus.

Comment: Is this answerer a duplicate account of the questioner's?

Comment: @RalphJ On the image on which you _only_ see the horizon, no Concorde window and no Concorde wing, only the Earth from cruise altitude. You can see a star on the upper left and another on the upper right of the dark sky. Or at least I assume it are stars.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune Yes it's me.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts fyi

Comment: Those specks look both too large and ***way*** too bright to be stars.  They're basically as bright as the clouds in daylight, and stars aren't nearly as bright as that.  Try taking a picture of the night sky on a clear, dark night with your phone's camera... you ***might*** get individual stars, but probably not.  Now try it with something moderately bright (like that cloud layer) in part of the photo... the camera won't see stars at all. I'd strongly suspect those specks are either on the camera lens or the aircraft window.

Comment: @RalphJ What would cause this specks? When taking an image of the sky from _within_ a spacecraft, it may happen that you get stars visible on it as there is the window in front of the camera. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/STSCPanel.jpg

Comment: What would cause the specs? "_I'd strongly suspect those specks are either on the camera lens or the aircraft window._" - @RalphJ

Comment: @FreeMan So what would cause them? As you can see in the linked image, the stars _can_ look 'way too bright' on it.

Comment: The white specs in the left-hand image of the 2nd row of pics _could_ be stars, but they could just as easily be some dust or a scratch or pit on the window. That's exactly what Ralph J said. The array of spots on the right-hand image in that row (inside the cockpit) is _definitely_ something on the window itself.

Comment: @FreeMan I agree with what you say about the cockpit image to the right, and this is what made me feel unsure if the dots in the other image are actually stars. But orbs of dust usually look like large circles. I hope someone can shed light on this.

Comment: "The specs" may be ice crystals, but one picture seems to have a star or planet visible.  We'll have to put in for a "moonroof" design on Concorde II for a more definitive answer.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni The Concorde II is currently being built by Boom Technology. It is important that it has good windows so one can see anything outside with one's own eyes, unlike in the Spike S-512 which wouldn't have windows but use cameras instead, and you wouldn't know whether it is something outside or an ice crystal on the camera's objective.